# How do you find which versions / libraries to import in the Gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In the Gradle, there is a dependency section where you can choose to import libraries for things like RecyclerView, Support library, etc.

How do you know what the latest versions are to import for everything? Is there a lookup somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preferences -> Appearance... -> System Settings -> Android SDK
(or click the Android downloader icon in the toolbar)

In there, change the tab to SDK Tools.

In the list of installed components, look for "Android Support Library".  The version number of that is the current version of the libraries you can use in your projects locally.

Comment: 23.2.1 currently? So I would use that suffix for everything?

Comment: If 23.2.1 is what you have installed, yes, for all the support library components you mentioned.

Comment: Is there a risk to using the new 24 alpha? Isn't alpha supposed to imply "experimental" or "not necessarily stable"?

Comment: I don't know, but I would be skeptical of anything with the word "alpha" in the version.

Answer (score 0):

[Link](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/tools/support-library/index.html) shows the revision history of the support libraries, though I have often encountered times when it has been out of date. [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/) also usually posts when a new version of the support libraries are released. The easiest way is just to use android studio, you will get a lint warning when there are updated versions of a library you are using is available.